# What shall function actually return, when it returns void *

Tags: c++, multithreading, compilation

I'm programming a multithread application and the function, that is handles new threads is declared like this:

```
void * Client::sendMessage(void *threadid) {
// some code without any return
}
```

I call this function by this:

```
// create new thread for outcomming messages
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL,
            c->sendMessage, (void *) fd);
```

It works quite well, but when I compile it with those flags in this command:
`g++ main.cpp -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -lncurses -pthread -o ChatApp`
, it keeps me getting messages like this:

```
Client.cpp: In static member function ‘static void* Client::sendMessage(void*)’:
Client.cpp:167:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

So my question is, what shall I actully return, to get rid of these warnings during compilation?

Comment: Umm... `nullptr` I guess. It's not really obvious what you need to return.

Comment: ...I don't need to return anything :D I just want to compile it without any warnings and I want to understand, what the compiler actually wants to tell me :)

Comment: Consider a similar question: "I have a function that returns `int`; what value should it return?" In both cases, we don't have enough information to answer.

Comment: If you don't need to return anything then why have you declared your method with a non-void return type?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, Maybe it's a callback. That seems like the logical explanation to me, that everything should implement one with that signature.

Comment: @KeithThompson some `int` of course...but I don't understand, what shall I return, when it's `void *`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I was following some tutorial... I tried to make it without `*`, just `void`, but it didn't work...

Comment: This looks like a callback function required by `pthread_create()`. In C, just `return NULL;`. In C++, there is `nullptr` as chris said.

Comment: @Dworza: Please understand that your question is currently impossible to answer ;)  We have no information on the context here, so we can give you absolutely no advice on what this function should be returning.

Comment: @chris returning `nullptr` solves the problem :) The probable reason, why I needed to use `void *` was written by user172818

Comment: @Dworza: Then return some `void*`, of course. Adding `return nullptr;` to your function will silence the compiler warning, but will *not* necessarily make your function work properly, any more than adding `return 0;` to an arbitrary `int` function means that `0` is the value it *should* be returning.

Comment: The problem is that the compiler doesn't realize that the function is never expected to return, so it prints that warning when it doesn't see a `return` statement.

Comment: @KeithThompson I think the issue is that his function never actually returns, it goes into an infinite loop until the thread is killed.

Comment: @Barmar, In that case, mark it as `[[noreturn]]`.

Comment: @chris Post that as an answer!

Comment: @Barmar, But I still don't know if it is the right answer.

Comment: @Barmar: Is that based on some information that the OP hasn't given us? How do you know that `// some code without any return` is an infinite loop? That seems like odd behavior for a function called `sendMessage`, which I'd expect to send a message and return (something or nothing) to its caller.

Comment: @Dworza, Could you clarify on the infinite loop idea?

Comment: @KeithThompson And that was, what I needed to know.. Maybe my post was a little bit confusing, but all the problem just was, that I didn't understand, what type should I return, when I need to return `void *` . Of course I didn't ask about returning anything according to the inner logic of that function..just needed to know, what actually `void *` means... And I needed that function to be declared as it is, to be able to handle new threads...

Comment: @KeithThompson His first comment said "I don't need to return anything"

Comment: @Dworza: You said in a comment that you "don't need to return anything". How do you know that? `void*` is a pointer type that doesn't specify what type it points to.

Comment: I've updated the post, so you can see the calling of this funciton. @KeithThompson there is no infinite loop.. And as I've said - it works well - just the compiler with `-pedantic` flag didn't like it without any return statement..

Comment: @Dworza: Telling is from the beginning that the function was being passed to `pthread_create` would have saved us all a lot of time.

Comment: @KeithThompson ah...sry for that.. I've thought, that it will be enough, when I write, that it handles new threads... I should paste that `pthread_create` calling as well... :-S

Comment: pthreads are just one of many thread implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the address of your `sendMessage` function as the third argument to `pthread_create`.

Calling `pthread_create` creates a new thread which terminates when the start routine (in this case, your `sendMessage` function) returns (or in any of several other circumstances). Returning a value from the start routine is equivalent to passing the same value to `pthread_exit()`. That `void*` value returned by the start routine can be made available to another thread in the same process if that thread calls `pthread_join`.

It's a `void*` value because `void*` is a generic pointer than can point to an object of any type. If you want to use this mechanism to pass information from a terminating thread to another thread, you'll need to decide on a mechanism to do so. If you don't need to pass such information, then it doesn't matter what your start routine returns; the simplest thing to do is `return nullptr;`.

Answer (score 1):

A `void *` is not the same as a void function. A `void *` is a pointer but it can more safely point to anything, in c++ you shouldn't need to use `void *` very much but what it should return is a pointer. In this case it looks like you might just have to return `threadid`. By the way in your case what is happening is the function is defaulting to return 0(so NULL) which might also be ok, hard to know from the amount of code provided

Comment: `it can point to anything` So can any other pointer type: `int *my_ptr = (int *) 0xBADF00D`.

Comment: Rather it can safely hold any type of pointer (though I don't think it has the same requirement for function pointers).

Comment: @chris: Apart from function pointers...

Comment: I wouldn't say there is anything particularly safe about void * but I will make the correction

Comment: Yeah, "safe" is a bit of a misnomer. I meant it's big enough to hold them. And @OliCharlesworth, I clarified that just as you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

Return whatever is consistent with the contract of your function. If the return is truly always  disregarded, consider changing your return type to void.